# UIVIew Shrinks while editing textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I'm having an unknown behaviour by my view controller. I'm presenting a ViewController A (Having Layouts/Size Classes enabled) from a ViewController B not using Autolayout/Size Classes. When it is displayed from any other ViewController. It works. But using this viewcontroller. It's not working. Every thing on the view shrinks when I tap on UITextField to add some data. See images.

ViewController Appears like this:

[image]

And then it becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: So no one knows any thing?

Comment: The navigation controller of ViewnController A is created in  View Controller B?

Comment: I'm presenting VC. Not Pushing. So why Navigation?

Comment: Because tha bar "strached" seem a navigation bar and  you can  present or push a ViewnController by its Navigation Controller that create the navigation bar.

Comment: No it's not a navigation bar. It's an independent VC

Comment: Use autoLayout entirely or don't use it at all. Mixing it may cause undesired behaviour.

Comment: Could you please post an answer on how you solved the same.